# Is there an easy way to implement app level IP whitelisting for nonprod environments on Heroku?

Tags: security

My organization hosts an app on Heroku, and the dev and qa environments (with swagger) are all accessible to the internet with no vpn required or firewalling/IP whitelisting. Isn't this strongly discouraged? And what can we do to implement whitelisting on Heroku?